# R code inside math notation R Markdown

Tags: r, r-markdown, mathjax

In R Markdown, I can get an inline r code chunk to run inside single `$` math notation (only with a `*` before), but not double `$$` math notation:

```
* $H_o = `r 1 + 1`$
```

works, but:

```
$H_o = `r 1 + 1`$
```

doesn't work, and neither does:

```
$$H_o = `r 1 + 1`$$
```

The double `$$` is more flexible being able to put math notation on multiple lines, but how can you add inline code chunks inside?

Comment: The final rendering works for me even though the preview in RStudio (2023.06.1 Build 524) renders the code chunk as text

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran your example and it worked fine for me! Here is a [link to the pdf](https://github.com/JustinMShea/stack-overflow/blob/master/pdf_documents/R_code_inside_math_notation_R_Markdown.pdf) and [github .md documents](https://github.com/JustinMShea/stack-overflow/blob/master/github_documents/R_code_inside_math_notation_R_Markdown.md) I generated. And here  is a [link to the rmarkdown document.](https://github.com/JustinMShea/stack-overflow/blob/master/Rmd/R%20code%20inside%20math%20notation%20R%20Markdown.Rmd)

I'm using R 3.4.1, knitr 1.16, and rmarkdown 1.6.

Perhaps you should check your version of rmarkdown and knitr. I have noticed over the years that version updates, and sometimes even using the most recent dev version, can fix a litany of small issues that arise.

Comment: Yeah wow.  I was looking at the inline code render in Rstudio without knitting the PDF.  Assumed that's how it would look, but it pops out fine.  In the RStudio inline render my examples show the math notation as ` r (1 + 1) `.

Comment: Yep, same for me, it doesn't show up unless I knit the pdf